# Deploy camel project in fuse fabric

Tags: java, jbossfuse, fuseesb

Following things i want to know to deploy camel projects in fuse fabric environment.
I have created bundle jars. These bundle jars work well in a non-fabric environment. i-e when i move these jars to deploy directory on jboss-fuse it works perfectly.
When the same jars are moved to child containers it does not work. Things that i have setup for fabric environment is as follow:

**Created Fabric container:**

```
fabric:create --new-user fadmin --new-user-password maskerkey --generate-zookeeper-password --resolver localip
```

**Child containers:**

```
fabric:container-create-child root node 2
```

How should i deploy same bundle jars to child containers? The following exception i am seeing when i deploy bundle jars:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle BUNDLE_NAME [139]: Unable to resolve 139.0: missing requirement [139.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.activemq.camel.component)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have fabric environment, you should never use `deploy/` directory. It's rather for prototyping purposes.

When you have created child containers using:

```
fabric:container-create-child root node 2
```

You have now two containers named `node1` and `node2`

A *bundle* in OSGi is just an *enhanced* JAR.

A (Karaf) *feature* is a collection of *bundles* (and possibly configurations), so you can install multiple bundles more easily.

A (Fabric) *profile* is a *declaration* of bundles, features, configurations and resources (roughly), so you can install multiple (karaf) features more easily.

Your error message means that there's no bundle already installed, that could satisfy a requirement of *your* bundle. More precisely, you lack a bundle that exports `org.apache.activemq.camel.component` package.

If you look at profiles and features available with Fuse, you'll see:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:info activemq-camel
Description of activemq-camel 5.11.0.redhat-vvv feature
----------------------------------------------------------------
Feature has no configuration
Feature has no configuration files
Feature depends on:
  activemq-client 5.11.0.redhat-vvv
  camel-spring [2.17,3)
  camel-jms [2.17,3)
  camel [2.17,3)
Feature contains followed bundles:
 mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-camel/5.11.0.redhat-vvv start-level=50
Feature has no conditionals.
```

(where `vvv` is given build of Fuse).

Now you have to create your *profile*:

```
profile-create myprofile
```

Add `activemq-camel` feature to it:

```
profile-edit --feature activemq-camel myprofile
```

Add your bundle to it:

```
profile-edit --bundle mvn:your-groupId/your-artifactId/your-version
```

And assign this profile to a container (containers)

```
container-add-profile node1 myprofile
```